# How to pass object[] to Activator.CreateInstance(type, params object[])

Tags: c#, .net, activator

I have a class which contains an empty constructor and one that accepts an array of objects as its only parameter. Something like...

```
public myClass(){ return; }
public myClass(object[] aObj){ return; }
```

This is the CreateInstance() method call that I use

```
object[] objectArray = new object[5];

// Populate objectArray variable
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(myClass), objectArray);
```

it throws `System.MissingMethodException` with an added message that reads
"Constructor on type 'myClass' not found"

The bit of research that I have done has always shown the method as being called

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(myClass), arg1, arg2);
```

Where arg1 and arg2 are types (string, int, bool) and not generic objects.
How would I call this method with only the array of objects as its parameter list?

Note: I have tried adding another variable to the method signature. Something like...

```
public myClass(object[] aObj, bool notUsed){ return; }
```

and with this the code executed fine.
I have also seen methods using reflection which were appropriate but I am particularly interested in this specific case. Why is this exception raised if the method signature does in fact match the passed parameters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cast it to `object`:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(yourType, (object) yourArray);
```

Comment: If his constructor takes an array, then that is a single item of the CreateInstance array, so it should be a nested array inside an item of the outer array.

Comment: @AaronLS: It is nested, because the parameter is declared with `params`.

Comment: Yes true, I was taking it a bit too literally probably.

Comment: I see now so the object array should be passed as a single parameter thanks guys!

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you have constructor:

```
class YourType {
   public YourType(int[] numbers) {
      ...
   }
}
```

I believe you would activate like so by nesting your array, the intended parameter, as a item of the params array:

```
int[] yourArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourType ), new object[] { yourArray });
```